# pclzip сжирает много памяти во время сжатия папки

Tags: php

Проблема в том, что при сжатии каталога на сервере почему-то идет утечка памяти. На локалке на вертриго данный фрагмент работает при 128мб памяти, а на сереврер даже 256 не хватает во время сжатия. Сжимает два каталога из папки инстал и один файл, далее почему-то создает очень большой временный файл (где-то на 500 - 900 мегабайт) и вываливается с ошибкой о нехватке памяти.

Сам архив в итоге выходит около 55м, не дожимает где-то 1 мегабайт (еще 1 папка и десяток файлов). В чем проблема, не могу понять...

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$catalog = "install";    
@unlink($catalog.".zip"); 
$archive = new PclZip($catalog.".zip");
$openDIR = opendir($catalog);
while ($scan = readdir($openDIR))
{
    if($scan == '.' || $scan == '..' ) continue;
    $list = $archive->add($catalog."/".$scan, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $catalog);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант могу предложить избавиться от цикла, обычно они любят память ;)
Тем более что у pclzip есть возможность указать сразу на папку, которую нужно сжать, а он уже сам всё сделает внутри.

```
$archive->create($catalog."/".$scan, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
```